# Selecting columns without specifying column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very strange scenario and would be highly grateful if you can help me out. I have one flat table of five fields, and I need to select everything from say the last three columns.

SAMPLE:

```
ID CODE BRAND T1 T2 
== ==== ===== == == 
1   KUU  RR4   1  2 
2   KUU  R56   2  1 
=====================
```

I need only the values of T1 and T2. The reason I need to get the last two columns is that the table is generated automatically from an Excel file, so the first three columns are static (ID, CODE, BRAND), and only last two columns are dynamic (T1, T2) and can be different next time, like (P1, P2), so I cannot do something like SELECT T1, T2 FROM sampleTable. I am totally stumped any help or advice would be great.

Comment: You mean to say that your database _structure_ is non-static?

Comment: yes the columns are dynamic ...

Comment: I already answered (see below), but let me point out that having to maintain a dynamic schema could prove painful in the future...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention php, but there it is in the tags so:

In your php script, you could select the whole shebang and still access the fields in a numeric order. For example:

```
$q=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM SAMPLE");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_NUM)) 
  {
  printf("col#4: %s -- col#5: %s",$row[3],$row[4]);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 4,5 FROM SampleTable;

4,5 specifies the column number in your table.